# AWSのEC2インスタンス上でrailsのbatchコマンド実行がエラーとなってしまい実行できない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2

EC2インスタンスに入り、`bundle exec rails routes` のような（作成したbatchの）コマンドを実行したいのですが、エラーとなり実行できませんでした。

エラーlogは以下のようになっていますが、何が悪かったか具体的にわからず困っています。
また、EC2インスタンス上にて作成されるlogをみても特に出力がなく原因特定に難航しています。

**同じように失敗するコマンド**

- `bundle exec rails routes`
- `bundle exec bin/rails routes`

※本当はもう少しエラーがあるのですが、以下のようにログ出力されたため、`--trace` をコマンドに付与して実行したところ 下記の（略）〜（略）の間のログが出力されました。
(See full trace by running task with --trace) //--traceを付ければ完全なログ見れるよー

```
rails aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- annotate

（略）

/var/www/cm-dev/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load_rakefile'
/var/www/cm-dev/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:703:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/var/www/cm-dev/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:104:in `block in load_rakefile'
/var/www/cm-dev/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/var/www/cm-dev/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:103:in `load_rakefile'
/var/www/cm-dev/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:22:in `block in perform'
/var/www/cm-dev/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:20:in `perform'
/var/www/cm-dev/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/var/www/cm-dev/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:20:in `perform'

（略）

Caused by:
Bootsnap::LoadPathCache::FallbackScan:
```

具体的な原因は "Bootsnap::LoadPathCache::FallbackScan" のようですが、ググってみてもこれ！といった情報が見つからずにいます。
どなたか原因の詳細やコマンドの実行方法についてご教示いただけないでしょうか。
または解析方法も教えていただけますと幸いです。

Comment: gemfileに'annotate'は含まれていますか？https://qiita.com/kou_pg_0131/items/ae6b5f41c18b2872d527

Comment: はい、含まれております、、